# If is ACF block template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to build blocks.

Here's a simple function I've written via functions.php:

```
<?php
function my_test_function() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'template-parts/blocks/hero/hero.php' ) ) {
        echo '<p>I appear via the hero.php template.</p>';
    }
    if ( is_page_template( 'template-parts/blocks/video/video.php' ) ) {
        echo '<p>I appear via the video.php template.</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Here's how I call the function via hero.php and video.php

```
<?php
    my_test_function();
?>
```

When I test this, nothing appears. I'm guessing the `is_page_template` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) doesn't work in this instance as it's technically not a page template.

Is there another function that might work with ACF block templates?

Comment: `is_page_template()` refer to the whole page template : the file starting with the template name on a php comment. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ I think you are testing only a template part instead of the page template

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm calling a template part. Do you know if there's a WordPress function I can use to get this working? I couldn't find anything via the documentation .

Comment: What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I'd like to build a condition within each of my block templates. If I'm in hero.php, for example, I'd like to set a condition. I'm building an image function that has lots of different conditions.

Comment: Is you blocks built with acf and flexible content ?

Comment: I'm using ACF blocks.

Comment: Ok I get it ! so `parse_blocks()` function could be a good starting point. I'll write you something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `parse_block()` : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/ then loop through blocks to check if blockName exist for this page :

```
function check_if_block_exist($block_handle) {
  $post = get_post(); 

  if(has_blocks($post->post_content)) {
    $blocks = parse_blocks($post->post_content);

    foreach( $blocks as $block ) {
      if($block['blockName'] === $block_handle) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```